# How to calculate MD5 hash concatenate with file name for all files within a directory

Tags: windows, command-line

I am looking for equivalent instructions in Windows Command Line, or any program that would produce the same output as the output of those commands.

```
# Linux
mkdir md5; md5sum * | awk '{system("cp "$2" md5/"$1"_"$2)}'
```

1. Create empty *md5* directory
2. Calculate *md5_hash* for all files within a directory
3. Concatenate *file's md5_hash  + '_' + file's name*
4. Copy newly created file *(md5_hash  + '_' + file's name)*  to md5 directory

Comment: install either `msys/MingW` or `Cygwin` and you don't have to give up any of the your linux skills? Else, there are usually windows equivalents of utitlities like `md5sum` available, which is the only unusual command above. Did you search for them? Then you can use http://batsh.org to give you the equivalent scripting cmds (move vs mv, copy vs cp, etc). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in correct direction. Although all of your suggested programs  does exactly what I need I decided to use `win-bash`. It is a simple archive with plenty of bash goodies inside. Moreover, it works without installation as  contrary to `msys/MingW` or `Cygwin`

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

@shellter pointed me in correct direction. Instead of trying to replicate Linux's commands in Windows Commander, it was easier to emulate Linux terminal (or bash programs) in Windows. The easiest solution was to install [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) (actually unzip). This simple archive contains many bash programs including md5sum.